# Heroku DataClip fails to retrieve data for some tables

Tags: sql, django, heroku

I've a DB hosted in Heroku.

Using DataClips I want to make a simple query to my table `Order`, but gives me an error:

```
SELECT * FROM Order;

Dataclip Error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Order"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM Order;
                      ^
```

However, I can apply the same query to other tables and it works, the difference is in the name of the table:

```
SELECT * FROM shop_product;
```

The DB was created by Django ORM.

The Table is called Order:

[image]

Django project structure:

[image]

Comment: you don't have a table "Order" if it was created by Django. Table names are always "<app_name>_<model_name>" in lowercase. Maybe "shop_order"?

Comment: @dirkgroten I've posted a picture. in the right side you can see the other tables start with the app name, like you say. Don't know why Order table doesn't.

Comment: Have you specified `db_table` in the `Order` model's `Meta` class maybe? Looking at your app, the table should have been called `order_order` by default.

Comment: @dirkgroten yes, it is set to: `db_table = 'Order'` what can I do? :(

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM "Order";` work? Or if this is still a project in progress, remove `db_table`, delete your migration files and restart your migrations with a fresh database.

Comment: @dirkgroten it worked with `"Order"`. Thank you.  It is not a work in progress, so this saved my day.

Comment: If in your Django shell you type `print(Order.objects.all().query)` you would see the SQL Django produces for your query. This would have shown your the quotes for example.